# I am trying to implement always encrypted on a partitioned table on column that is not used for partitioning the table

Tags: always-encrypted

I am trying to implement always encrypted using deterministic type on a partitioned table on column that is not used for partitioning the table.I am getting below error:

```
Column 'SubsidiaryId' is partitioning column of the index 'XYZ'. 
Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of index key. 
Cannot create Index or constraint. See previous errors.
```

Comment: It will help if you edit the question to show your code.

Comment: It would also help if you identified the database product...